# Is php|architect any good?

Tags: php, publications

Kind of a hard topic to search for, as architect turns up a lot about software architects instead.

After 8 months of PHP self-study, I finally stumbled across the php|architect site. The length of time it took me to find it makes me suspicious of its quality.

3 related questions:

- do professional PHP coders read/care about php|architect?
- is it a good source for PHP beginners?
- assuming yes to either of the above, how far back in the archives to articles remain relevant? (ex: does stuff written about PHP4 still matter?)

Comment: For people with php knowledge but who don't know the site you could include it as link to safe them a google http://www.phparch.com/

Comment: I just checked it out, and didnt see anything there that made me want to bookmark it.

Comment: Do you mean the magazine? Or their training? I have used both and met other pro PHP programmers who read it. I attended some training a few years ago and it was excellent but the trainer - Paul Reinheimer - has since left. I would say the topics in the magazine are a little too advanced for beginners.

Comment: Also I think they have stopped printing the magazine so its only available in digital format. Plus I think they lost their 'official' Zend partner training status.

Comment: Hey there.  Just ran into this (old) page and posts.  Wanted to give an update here.  I'm one of the owners of php[architect] magazine.  My partners and I acquired the company at the beginning of 2013 (and hence the slight re-branding).   Just wanted to let you know that we brought the magazine back to print!  You can still purchase a digital only version if you wish, but the print copies are available again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been subscribed to the magazine for several years. It's not beginner level material, but the content has been consistently good and useful. There are articles on specific projects, frameworks, tools, best practices, coding techniques and so on.

Sadly they discontinued their print edition some time ago (really wish they hadn't - that print magazine was something I looked forward to seeing in the mailbox each month) so the subscription is now digital only. I suspect to reduce costs.

They are still publishing, and they send me an email each month to let me know the new issue is available to download. It's still good content, but reading on a screen is just not the same as holding the magazine in hand.

Comment: Hello Grant - As I posted to another comment above on this question.  php[architect] (new branding) is now under new ownership, and we've brought the print edition back again due to consistent requests from our customers!

Answer (score 2):

I have been into PHP development for over 5 years now & I really find the articles very relevant & helpful. It's clearly not aimed at PHP beginners but at the intermediate/expert programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Am I the first one who has been developing in php for a few years now and never heard of php architect?

> do professional PHP coders read/care about php|architect?

I have never heard of it.

> is it a good source for PHP beginners?

With a word like architect I would at first glance say no.

> assuming yes to either of the above, how far back in the archives to articles remain relevant? (ex: does stuff written about PHP4 still matter?)

Not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I bought and read PHP Architect magazine thoroughly, then it become increasingly hard to physically find at bookstores and newsstand plus I moved away from core PHP development.  Having said that I always found the articles useful and relevant at the time and would occasionally go back a few months to re-read articles.

Haven't looked at a copy in years so I cannot attest to the value of the articles anymore plus I don't think it's available in print format so if your looking to physically have something in your hands your out of luck.

CB

Answer (score -2):

Just yesterday while cleaning out boxes full of magazines, I found a June 2008 copy mixed amnong my Website magazines.

I used to love reading this magazine. They were like my News Press Photographer's Association magazine. Covered a topic. Like this issue was about EAV Modeling (Not just for medical records after all).

I'll gonna look them up again, although a lot of my code is in VBScript/ASP I still have lots in PHP.

Comment: You are not answering the question

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't able to add a comment. I can only respond to comments on my posts. However, by comparing an issue where it uses PHP for EAV modeling outside of the medical field I thought said I was impressed with it like some others above, I just didn't come out and say it outright. I can edit the post to say I was impressed on how it took a data modeling system for medical records and applied it to other fields?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that you were actually talking about their magazine. In how far that is relevant to the current site I don't know. As for commenting, [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site)